# Can a Sabertooth 2x25 Motor Controller be used with ROS?

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a sabertooth 2x25 motor controller that I was planning on using for me "real world robot." Does it have to be connected through an arduino or Pi? If so does anyone have an example or a link to a tutorial?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255833/can-a-sabertooth-2x25-motor-controller-be-used-with-ros?/) by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need some kind of microcontroller that is supported by ROS,  Arduino and Raspberry Pi are. For Arduino, take a look at the `rosserial_arduino` [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0